# Is it possible to have two independent toolbars in DataTables

Tags: datatables, tabletools

I managed to get *TableTools* integrated into *DataTables* and set up my own "toolbar". 
Setting the dom option to  `dom : '<"H"fr>t<"F"Tlp>'`
generates a result like this:

[image]

I wonder it it would be possible to create a second toolbar that contains different buttons and add this new bar to another location (like the header).

Something like this:

[image]

If I specify the following  `dom : '<"H"Tfr>t<"F"Tlp>'` I will only get the same toolbar twice.